# How to upgrade a liferay theme from 7.0 to 7.4?

Tags: themes, liferay, liferay-7.4

I'm following the official tutorial to update a theme from 7.0 to 7.2 https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360029316831-Running-the-Upgrade-Task-for-7-0-Themes, the process is successful but I need to update to liferay 7.4 and I can't find official documentation or information on how to continue from here, I try to deploy the war on my local server with 7.4 but it says which is not compatible with this version of Liferay. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 years between Liferay 7.0 and 7.4 - and a lot has changed in the frontend world. I'd suggest you either just create a new theme, or (better) check if just using a stylebook with a stock theme is sufficient. A stylebook should be a lot easier to migrate to future versions than a full theme.

I believe that it's technically possible to upgrade a theme, but wouldn't bother doing so. As you have an existing theme, it should be relatively quick to get to where you need to be - plus you'll have the opportunity to make those little adjustments that you likely had an eye on for the past couple of years.